# More than One Nth-Child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can I use more than one nth-child selctor for a class?

For example,

```
.span4:not(nth-child(1)):nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red
}
```

I want to target the 4th, 7th, 10th, etc., except the 1st one.

If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combined selector `:not(nth-child(1)):nth-child(3n+1)`, but it is easier and simpler to use `:nth-child` with an argument that matches the children you wish to match, in this case `:nth-child(3n+4)`.

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought of that! Silly me, I keep thinking n starts at 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon before `nth-child`:

```
           |
.span4:not(:nth-child(1)):nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: red
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hcY2/

Comment: OP was asking for a better way, not wondering why this way does not work. FWIW, I think 3n+4 might do it.

Comment: That works, but I think Jukka found a better way of doing it. Thanks though!